# Sort multidimensional array WITHOUT KEYNAMES in PHP, case insensitive

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => space
            [1] => Venus
            [2] => NASA
            [3] => apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => link1
            [1] => link2
            [2] => link3
            [3] => link4
        )
)
```

I want to sort it, case INsensitively, by the [0] term. How can I do this? All answers I've found show how to do this only if the array has keynames.

If that's not clear, I want this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => NASA
            [2] => space
            [3] => Venus
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => link4
            [1] => link3
            [2] => link1
            [3] => link2
        )
)
```

If it's easier with keynames, or it can't be done unless there are keynames (which I doubt), how can I modify my original array to contain names "keywords" for [0] and "links" for [1]?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code merges the multiple dimension version back into a key/value single array which makes it easy to sort, and then optionally brings it back to multiple dimensions. Demo here: https://3v4l.org/CStsS

```php
$data = [
    ['space', 'Venus', 'NASA', 'apple'],
    ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4'],
];

// Convert the multiple dimensional array to avsingle
$merged = array_combine(...$data);

// Sort by key
uksort($merged, fn($a, $b) => strcasecmp($a, $b));

var_dump($merged);

// If it needs to be converted back to a multiple dimension array
$data = [
    array_keys($merged),
    array_values($merged),
];

var_dump($data);
```

**EDIT**

Another answer was provided by @lukas.j that used the built-in `array_multisort` function, but has since been deleted. In theory, being a native function, that code might be more performant for large arrays, and, with a couple of optimizations, it also skips the intermediary variables. I personally avoid multiple dimension arrays whenever possible (personal preference) so I’ve never used that function, but I think it works here perfectly.

```php
$arr = [
    [ 'space', 'Venus', 'NASA', 'apple' ],
    [ 'link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4' ]
];

array_multisort($arr[0], SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE, $arr[1]);

print_r($arr);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/saI1C

Comment: Thanks! That works in my actual code, but for some reason it won't work on code I'm testing with https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp. Anyway, it works on my local server so case closed. 

really appreciate it!

Just one more question.

If I had this:

$data = [
    ['space', 'Venus', 'NASA', 'apple','space'],
    ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4','link5'],
];

how would I delete the second 'space' and its 'link5'?

Comment: I test almost all of my code on 3v4l, so I can’t say why it doesn’t work on another site. As for your comment about deletion, I think that would best be suited by a new dedicated question, possibly referencing this question, if it makes sense to do so. However, a quick (maybe hacky) way is to reverse the arrays before combining, since that function lets duplicates win: https://3v4l.org/VBLtt